# Highcharts :: Need to split y-axis from primary body of chart. Can I display this axis separately from the Highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I have a situation where I need to remove all margins from a highchart and remove the x/y axis so it fills a series of columns in a table completely.

I did that, no problem. Chart goes to the extremes as needed.

What I need now is that pesky yaxis I already removed...but displayed in a table cell outside of the existing highcharts object.

It would seem easy, as though I could just set the overflow property of yaxis to 'visible' and play with the offset...which would work however this would only work if I wanted to re-position the axis within the boundaries of the highchart object. I want him in a different cell entirely.

Is there anyone who has had experience in this situation? Is it going to require me to have a secondary highchart with only a y-axis?

Best answer gets a green check.

---

EDIT :: I now have dispersed each 'day' into their own column (more bars coming per day [scheduled,actual,etc...]). In order to keep the scales lined up, I manipulate the yAxis:max property and set them all to a derived value.

In the open column (currently w/ text Hourly Trends) is where I would put an additional highchart module with no series data but with the same min/max/tickInterval.

The next big leap will be to see the data is alive and changes w/ schedule. May have to start another thread for that one, no?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new HC object with no data but only the yAxis (making sure it is the right scale, etc). Perhaps add the same series of data to it but hide the series? Add it to the location you want. This seems kludge and not very good practice. Each business use is different but why would you want this?

EDIT based on comment of business rules:
Why not come at this from a different direction and have the individual chart elements (the bars/points/etc) be a single point chart. This way you have one chart per column. You can then set up the yAxis to be text and not worry about the position. If we could see an example of the page layout and the desired result that would help.

Comment: Oh, the answer is related to how we're displaying the data along with the other page elements. Think of it as a weekly schedule with data correlating to each day of the week shown below in the appropriate column. There's the left gutter I use for addition info and we want the axis to appear there, so the first day of the week isn't the only chart 'series' that has a vertical axis sharing the space.